# Load x509certificate(.cer) in android app

Tags: android, x509certificate2

I get a `x509certificate` from web service and I want to load it on screen for user.

I wrote this code. I had certificate in `t` variable.  but I don't know how to display it on screen.

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(cert.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT));
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509","BC");
java.security.cert.Certificate c = cf.generateCertificate(is);
X509Certificate t = (X509Certificate) c;
```

Comment: `X509CertificateHolder x509CertificateHolder = new X509CertificateHolder(
       x509Certificate.getEncoded());
     X500Name x500Name = x509CertificateHolder.getSubject();`

Comment: Thank you Alessiox, It is ok.  I can show a popup and display certificate detail as subject field but It is beter for me open certificate on screen